Excel formula with dynamic inputs & dynamic outputs
I have two table ranges in excel. One will have the conditions and equivalent formulas to be used for those conditions. And in other table, I have conditions and their input values that should be given to the formulas. I need to substitute the inputs with the relevant condition formula and get the output. How to do it directly in MS excel without using VBA



I've tried using What if analysis and Lambda formulas. But in anymeans I couldn't get that.

How excel will know 2Y=2*I7? Why not I5 or I4....?

@Harun24hr That's precisely the purpose of a LAMBDA function (or a LET function)

There are many options, here I choose to include an old Excel v4.0 macro function called EVALUATE(). I made a custom function through name manager called EVAL() which refers to:
=LAMBDA(x,EVALUATE(x))

Then I simply went over your data using MAP(), gave all values a variable and used SUBSTITUTE() to make a mathematical sound string to be evaluated:

Formula in G2:
=MAP(D2:D7,E2:E7,F2:F7,LAMBDA(x,y,z,EVAL(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(x,A2:B4,2,0),E$1,"*"&y),F$1,"*"&z),"+*","+"))))


Thanks for the response. I can't find EVALUATE function in excel. Am using Office 365, how to add it. Also my conditions will not only have + & *. It also like below
D = 0.5X + MAX(0.5X,0.33Y)>

@SaravananManamohan The EVALUATE function is an old function, from before VBA existed.  While it still exists, for legacy purposes / backwards-compatibility, it is hidden: it does not appear anywhere, and will only work when it is part of a Name Function, not as part of a normal Worksheet Function.  It will run any compatible code that is passed to it as a text string, which is generally a sign of it being a dangerous/unsafe function, to avoid unless absolutely necessary.

Here is one way of achieving the desired outputs, this completely based on the context of the OP:


• Formula used in cell H2
=LET(
     α, TEXTSPLIT(VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$B$4,2,0),,"+"),
     δ, F2:G2*(1-ISERR(FIND(F$1:G$1,α))),
     φ, HSTACK(δ,IFERROR(--TEXTBEFORE(α,F$1:G$1),0)),
     SUM(BYROW(IF(φ=0,1,φ),PRODUCT)))


NOTE: In the BYROW() construction I have used ETA LAMBDA() probably this is applicable for those using MS365 Office Insiders if one don't have the access then try to construct it with LAMBDA() which should give the same output as is by the one answered here. 


my conditions will not only have + & *. It also like below D = 0.5X + MAX(0.5X,0.33Y.
How to include those

As you say, a LAMBDA is probably your best method.  (Although, personally, I often write more complicated ones out as a LET formula in a cell for testing, and convert it to a LAMBDA in a Named Range afterwards, when it works!)
So, our first step is to define the inputs: let's go with var_x, var_y, and cond
=LAMBDA(var_x, var_y, cond, [FUNCTION])

Now, we need to decide on our function.  To begin with, we need to change the output based on cond, so let's use SWITCH for that:
=LAMBDA(var_x, var_y, cond, SWITCH(cond, "A", [FUNC1], "B", [FUNC2], "C", [FUNC3]))

Then we just take the 3 formulae you have already worked out, and use those as [FUNC1], [FUNC2], and [FUNC3]:
=LAMBDA(var_x, var_y, cond, SWITCH(cond, "A", (2*var_x)+var_y, "B", (2*var_x)+(2*var_y)+(3*var_x*var_y), "C", (2*var_y)+var_x+(2*var_x*var_y)))

Stick into a Named Range, called something like foo_Stack, and call it like a function:
=foo_stack(H7, I7, G7)


I was just wondering if it would be possible to parse the formula string character by character. It works for the sample data, but is only valid for single digit 'coefficients':
=LET(str,XLOOKUP(E2,A$2:A$4,B$2:B$4),
 SUM(REDUCE({0,1},MID(str,SEQUENCE(LEN(str)),1),
  LAMBDA(a,c,
    IF(c="+",HSTACK(a,1),
    HSTACK(DROP(a,,-1),TAKE(a,,-1)*IFERROR(--c,XLOOKUP(c,F$1:G$1,F2:G2))))))))



you can solve the problem with a single (I mean two single :) ) IF function. If you want solve just the case above, and it is not a part of a much bigger one, you could try this simple approach: if the condition is "A" (in the G3 cell), than calculate the formula with the given parameters. Your J3 function should be like this, and you can copy it down to the whole J column
IF
    (
        G3="A";
        2*H3+I3;
        IF
            (
                G3="B";
                2*H3+2*I3+3*H3*I3;
                2*I3+H3+2*H3*I3
            )
    )


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
